# Printing PDF differs on different printers

Tags: pdf, printing, itext

I created A4 PDF document using iTextSharp. It contains simple table of which every cell in fact is label on the page. I drew it by using PdfContentByte, so the size of the programmatically drawing area is 595 x 842 points. Thus I drew rectangles (as table cells) using points as units.

I fixed the size and place (in points) of printing content by checking printed pages on my printer. I used Acrobat Reader and options: **without scaling** ('None') and **default paper size 8.3' x 11.7'**

Now if I print the same PDF on different printer the content (table) is **shifted** to the left or/and top direction. So the distances between page's edges and the outer frame of the table are different on different printers. Sometimes the content is cut but I know that different printers have different printing area - so it understood.

But I can not understand why it is shifted. Are they others parameters that I don't know?

Comment: So you're saying that the dimensions of the rectangles are the same (no scaling), but the offset is different on different printers (you might add: using different printer drivers). That's something that can't be fixed. It's not an iTextSharp thing; it's not an Adobe Reader thing; it's a printer/printer driver related thing.

Comment: Yes, the rectangles are the same. So in this situation I have to fix the left and top offset dependently on printer. Thanks.